# Retrieve column Default with Derby DB via JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I have a table with a column defined like this:

```
Country VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'US'
```

When I try to detect this default with JDBC it fails. Basically when I use `DatabaseMetaData.getColumns` the result does not contain the `COLUMN_DEFAULT` column.  It is there when I try this with H2.

Any ideas how to get the default with Derby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try for COLUMN_DEFAULT? Or for COLUMN_DEF? According to the Javadoc I think it should be COLUMN_DEF.

Also, what version of Java and of JDBC are you using? I think that Derby only added COLUMN_DEF as part of the JDBC 4.0 support, which may require Java 1.6.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know where I read that the column name was "COLUMN_DEFAULT". You're right the spec says "COLUMN_DEF".